# PowerApp DataCardValue.Text Returning as blank when not blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

[image]

It should be an easy question but I cant figure this out, I have a Form In a power app I am developing. The Datacard has text called TEST but for some reason, this is returning as Blank.

I want the button to only be clickable when all of the data card values contain text otherwise it is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to do the following two steps:

1. Set the form mode - Whenever you work with the **Edit Form** component you need to specify in which mode you are going to work. Since you want to add a new record to the list, you need to set the **Form Mode** as `NewForm`. You can set `OnVisible` property of the current screen or `OnSelect` property of the button (if you are navigating from any other screen) as `NewForm(Form1)`. You can find more ways to do so and more insight over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-form).
2. To enable or disable the button as per your requirement, set the `DisplayMode` property of the button as:

```
If( 
    Or( 
       IsBlank(Field1.Text), 
       IsBlank(Field2.Text),
       IsBlank(Field3.Text), 
       IsBlank(Field4.Text)
      ),
    DisaplayMode.Disabled,
    DisaplayMode.Edit
)
```

**Source**: [PowerApp DataCardValue.Text Returning as blank when not blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78062584/powerapp-datacardvalue-text-returning-as-blank-when-not-blank) - Thanks to @SumitSingh.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `= Blank()` instead of `IsBlank()`:

```
If(DataCardValue1.Text = Blank(), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)
```

> The IsBlank function tests for a blank value or an empty string. The test includes empty strings to ease app creation since some data sources and controls use an empty string when there is no value present. **To test specifically for a blank value use if( Value = Blank(), ... instead of IsBlank.** The IsBlank function considers empty tables as not blank, and IsEmpty should be used to test a table.

Source: [Blank, Coalesce, IsBlank, and IsEmpty functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-isblank-isempty)